# How to count percentage in gridcontrol devexpress based on value from another column

Tags: c#, count, sum, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have data in a devexpress grid control. I have tried to summarize items in the grid.

Here is the image:

[image]

**PROGRESS** result is the comparison of two data rows in the grid control.
How can I get the percentage value in **PROGRESS** column based on the value in **ISFINISH**?

here is the code that i have tried:

```
private void bandedGridView1_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "PROGRESS") //PROGRESS
    {
        //int markVal = Convert.ToInt32(bandedGridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "ISFINISH"));
        string val = Convert.ToString(bandedGridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "TANGGALBACA"));
        if(val !="")
        {
            //GET SUM OF ISFINISH COLUMN BY KATEGORI
            GridGroupSummaryItem item = new GridGroupSummaryItem();
            GridSummaryItem item1 = bandedGridView1.GroupSummary.Add();
            item.FieldName = "ISFINISH";
            item.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum;
            item.Tag = 1;
            item.DisplayFormat = "{0:n0}"; //sum
            var sum = item.SummaryValue.ToString(); //bandedGridColumn7 is column by fieldname "ISFINISH"

            //GET COUNT OF ISFINISH COLUMN BY KATEGORI
            GridSummaryItem item2 = bandedGridView1.GroupSummary.Add();
            item2.FieldName = "ISFINISH";
            item2.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Count;
            item2.Tag = 1;
            item2.DisplayFormat = "{0}"; //count
            var count = item2.SummaryValue.ToString(); //bandedGridColumn7 is column by fieldname "ISFINISH"

            //GET RESULT AND CONVERT TO PERCENTAGE BETWEEN SUM AND COUNT OF INSFINISH COLUMN
            int hasil = (Convert.ToInt32(sum) / Convert.ToInt32(count)) * 100;
            e.DisplayText = hasil.ToString(); //HERE IS THE RESULT THAT I WANNA BE PERCENTAGE IN PROGRESS COLUMN
        }
    }
}
```

but, it doesn't work, need help, thanks

Comment: Please include any code that is relevant to this problem.

Comment: @dcreight i have included the code,.. so sorry be late to response,.. can u help it? thanks